# css - using cursors sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

```
.fancybox-inner {
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#EEE;
cursor: //url to an independent cursor image
 }
```

But what if my cursors (3) are all together in one css sprite image, how I can reference background-position, width, height values of the cursor property.

something like

```
cursor .fancybox-inner OR .fancybox-inner:hover cursor{
background: url(../img/cursors.png) no-repeat;
background-position: -32px 0;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
 }
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to use sprites as a cursor image, not quite sure tho. Good question!

Comment: I thought so, Im just curious ..couldn't find anything on google..

Comment: There is only one way to make your cursor a sprite that I can think of... http://www.cursors-4u.com/cursor/2012/02/09/sprite-13.html

Comment: `cursor` is not an DOM/HTML object and so you cannot style it with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Although the cursor property allows for x and y values, they are not used for background position, but rather for the coordinates of **the cursor's hotspot**

This is the syntax for the cursor property: (see [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/cursor/url))

```
cursor:  [<uri> [<x> <y>]?,]* keyword
```

For example:

```
.foo  {
    cursor:  auto;
    cursor:  url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto;
}
```

> The example will set the hotspot to be the pixel at (4,12) from the
>   top left (0,0).